# How to play Red5 streaming at all smart devices?

Tags: android, ios, streaming, video-streaming, red5

I have installed red5 server on ubuntu 12.04 lts at AWS instance. I have successfully streamed my live stream using with Adope live encoder and play it with jwplayer on websites. Now I need to play my live stream on all smart devices. I have referred so many forums but I did not get the good solution for this. I have some restriction to play on mobile.

1. do not play with Flash browser at all smart-device. need to play it's own player when they connected to my website.
2. Is there any possible to play my live streaming with html5 video Tag

How can I achieve this setup? I know the red5 server only stream RTMP protocol. I want to re-stream to android, iphone, blackberry, Nokia, and also all smart devices and tab.

Answer (score 2):

In practice you need to send the screams in three types:

- HLS for IOS/Windows/BB devices
- RTMP/RTMPT/RTMPS for browser based Flash clients (or AIR based native apps)
- RTSP for Android/BB devices (as HLS should but rarely does work on Android devices)
- Additionally there are some vendor specific technologies like Microsoft Smooth Streaming or webM by Google

You can use a streaming CDN like ScaleEngine.com to transcode and supply the necessary bandwidth to have streaming for all devices (RTMP for browsers, HLS for iOS devices and RTSP for Android). If you are inexperienced and you won't have terabytes of traffic, this might fit the bill.

If you are interested in a self hosted solution, a combination of:

- Red5/Wowza/nginx-rtmp for recording management
- FFmpeg for transcoding
- nginx-rtmp for HLS
- crtmp-server for RTPS

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is no all in one solution. The ONLY way to stream live video in iOS is HLS. Some versions of Android may support HLS. I have not idea what formats blackberry and Nokia support. You will need to research this.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your mobile app [with Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html) (with either Adobe Flash or [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org)), then your mobile app will support live audio/video streaming - on iOS, Android and BlackBerry 10 platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution to mobiles can be done with Wowza rtmp server packetisers for iOS HLS and RTP playback. 
But you need to stream in supported formats/codecs.

If you stream with a web based flash broadcasting tool, stream will not be compatible with iOS because Flash does not encode AAC, so you need to transcode it.

Transcoding can be done with Wowza Transcoder addon or ffmpeg as available with VideoWhisper Live Streaming that can produce a HTML5 video for Safari playback (on iOS / desktop).